# Stored procedure execution from job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs, ssis-2012

I have a problem with a JOB execution, the case is the next:

I have a job with category (Uncategorized Local) than have 1 step with "Transact SQL script" type.

The transact code is:

```
DECLARE     @fecha_inicio   DATETIME,
            @fecha_fin      DATETIME,
            @fecha_inicio_p VARCHAR(10),
            @fecha_fin_p    VARCHAR(10),
            @vc_mensaje_error AS VARCHAR(255)

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @fecha_inicio_p = par_valor1 
    FROM parametro 
    WHERE par_codigo_dominio = '000213' and par_codigo = 'FI'

    SELECT @fecha_fin_p = par_valor1 
    FROM parametro 
    WHERE par_codigo_dominio = '000213' and par_codigo = 'FF'

    SELECT @fecha_inicio = CONVERT(DATETIME, @fecha_inicio_p, 103)
    SELECT @fecha_fin = DATEADD(D,+1,CONVERT(DATETIME, @fecha_fin_p, 103))

    EXEC usp_p_broad_maestra_docvar  @fecha_inicio,@fecha_fin,'E'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    select @vc_mensaje_error = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    raiserror(@vc_mensaje_error,16,1)                              
END CATCH
```

The stored procedure does:

1. Truncate a table
2. Insert Into Select... UNION SELECT.... UNION SELECT...
3. call a job to use ssis to generate a file
4. Write Log

The problem is than when I execute the job, it never terminates and I have to cancel execution.

But when I don't use a stored procedure and the code put into JOB the job terminates ok.

Please your help maybe there are differences in the execution a stored procedure into job versus execute stored procedure code into job.

Thanks

Comment: maybe your job definition cause loop. I suggest, you comment the procedure in job and try. if it worked, something is wrong in proc. then comment out some part of codes in your proc and do this approach to finally catch the issue in your process

Comment: does it complete when run without job (manually from ssms)?

Comment: nothing in the this stored proc looks bad off hand.  but you reference "EXEC usp_p_broad_maestra_docvar" and we cannot see the code in it which as Flicker suggests could have an infinite loop or something going on.

Comment: Hi to all, thanks for your response.

Comment: When i run mannually the proc terminate ok.

Comment: i want to know what is the differencia to execute a exec into job versus execute a query in to job because with query work ok.